# How to pop sections of pandas dataframe based on row values

Tags: python, pandas

I have a large spreadsheet of over 3 million individual mammals (1 individual per row). I am trying to group these individuals by species so that I can perform separate analyses on each species represented. 

I am currently using the following line to generate separate dataframes for each species which I can the analyze.

```
speciesFrames = [mammals.loc[mammals.scientificname == species] for species in speciesList]
```

This process understandably takes a fair bit of time. I'm wondering if this can be sped up by discarding the sections of the `mammals` dataframe that I've already duplicated in `speciesFrames`? If so, how can I accomplish this?

I've trying variations of the following line, but each results in a separate error.

`speciesFrames = [mammals.pop(mammals.scientificname == species) for species in speciesList]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try `groupby` and you do not need create the `speciesList` here.

```
speciesFrames =[x for _,x in mammals.groupby('scientificname')]
```

Comment: Indeed you can use groupby for that. Just a few more ideas/comments:  1). If your df is that large, maybe you should iterate through groups and perform analysis within the loop scope, just to save your memory. 2) maybe you should parse your species as a categorical column, this will speed up filtering. 3) again, maybe you should use species as part of the multiundex, and use 'pd.indexslice` instead of grouping`